# How to dynamically generate OJET components using document.createElement

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, oracle-jet

Is there a way to dynamically generate ojet components using document.createElement()?
e.g.

```
var ss = document.createElement('oj-select-single');
ss.setAttribute("data","[[arrayData]]");
div.appendChild(ss)
```

I have tried setting attributes but the component does not show on UI. However there is a node created on the DOM. I think there is some problem with the ko bindings. But this method doesn't work for any ojet component.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are updating the DOM, you have to apply knockout binding again. Adding `ko.applyBindings(this, ss);` after your code should fix your issue. Take a look at the working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/beagle213/gdcq218f/10/)

Comment: Thanks @BEAGLE . Just one question... Does the inputText (any input component) have to be appended inside of a form element compulsorily?

Comment: Not necessarily, you add any Oracle JET component inside any element.  Make sure you are referring to the newly created element in `ko.applyBindings(this, newElement);`